# Плагин Polylang, как перевести текст в виджете?

Tags: wordpress, локализация

Wordpress 4.0 установлен плагин Polylang 1.5.5
Имеется ли какой-то тег для перевода текста?
Например: `<polylang=ru>русский текст</polylang> <polylang=en>английский</polylang>`
Нужно для перевода некоторых фраз в плагинах и виджетах.

Comment: Прояснил этот вопрос у разработчика плагина.
Такой возможности нет.

Answer (score 1):

У Polylang есть свои собственные маленькие функции, полезные для таких целей. Конкретно в этом случае, есть 3 варианта:

1. Локализация строки обычным методом WordPRess - в шаблоне находим где этот текст и оборачиваем его в функцию _e() или __(). После этого делаем перевод строки в POedit, Как обычно.
2. Локализация строки точно так же, как в п.1, только вместо внешнего POedit ставим плагин Loco Translate и переводим строку прямо в админке.
3. Вместо функций _e() или **() используем функции pll**(), pll_e() вместе с pll_register_string() и переводим в админке WordPress на странице настроек Polylang. Документация.

В любом случае, придется ковыряться в коде.

Comment: *Документация* — тут, вероятно, подразумевалась какая-то внешняя ссылка.